# elastic DSL query result from another query

Tags: elasticsearch, join, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

can anyone help me to translate below SQL query to ELasticSearch DSL form for document selections?

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE source_id IN (select source_id FROM table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This JOIN semantics does not translate to Elasticsearch. If your index had parent/child mapping - you might be able to achieve what you want to do. Another option is to do a two-pass query.

This blog post gives an idea of how relations are modeled in Elasticsearch - [Managing Relations in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch)

Comment: could you give me an hint on "Another option is to do a two-pass query." method ?  or any doc link